# When do open affine subschemes of equidimensional schemes are again equidimensional?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $X$ be an **equidimensional** scheme satisfying the properties $P_1,\ldots,P_n$.
Could someone please give me an example (with a reference or proof) of $P_1,\ldots, P_n$ such that the following statement is true?

> Every open affine subscheme of $X$ is equidimensional

I am mainly interested in the case where $X$ is **neither irreducible nor reduced**.

Comment: being equidimensional is a local property, so it holds for every open affine subscheme automatically

Comment: @ user45150 What is your definition of equidimensional such that it is 'local'? Irreducible components do all have the same dimension? I don't see how this is directly inherited by subschemes. Could you please explain this?

Comment: that all local rings at closed points have the same dimension

Comment: But from the definition I use we cannot derive yours: Look at Liu - Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic of Curves Exercise 2.5.3 (b).

Answer (score 0):

At least for the onedimensional case there are some results:

> **Lemma**: Let $X$ be an equidimensional scheme of dimension 1 and let $U$ be an affine open subscheme of $X$. Then $U$ is again onedimensional and equidimensional if it contains at least two distinct points from which at least one is closed.

**Proof**:
Let $U = \operatorname{Spec}{R}$ be an open subscheme of $X$ and let $Y$ be an irreducible component 
which has non-trivial intersection with $U$. By assumption, $Y$ has dimension one and 
thus there is some chain $Z_0 \subsetneq Z_1 \subset Y$ of closed irreducible subsets of $Y$. But 
since $Y$ is irreducible, we can wlog assume that $Z_1 = Y$ (otherwise $Y$ would have 
dimension 2). Now there are two things left to show:

1. If $Z_0 \cap U$, $Z_1 \cap U \neq \emptyset$, then $Z_0 \cap U \subsetneq Z_1 \cap U$
2. $Z_0$ has non-trivial intersection with $U$

**Ad 1**: Assume $\emptyset \neq Z_0 \cap U = Z_1 \cap U$, then $Z_1 = Z_1\setminus (Z_1 \cap 
U) \cup Z_0$, which is a contradiction regarding the irreducibility of $Z_1$.

**Ad 2**: Assume there is some closed point $P \in Y \cap U$. Then $\{P\} \subsetneq Y$ and $\{P\} \cap U \neq \emptyset$. To ensure the assumption, we only need to be sure that $U$ has at least one closed point which is not already the whole space.

Obviously we cannot use the same kind of argument in the higher dimensional case.